# How call OnPropertyChanged in double embedded data in xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding

I have a Content page, which contain CollectionView inside CarouselView.
First time when the page is loading the double embedded binding is work fine. Show everithing correctly.
But when i try to change embedded property value nothing happen. How update these properties?

```
  formChooseElement.formViewerElements[0].formViewerElementAnswares[0].color=Color.Green;
```

Like:

```
 <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding formViewerElements}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>                  
                <Label Text="{Binding text}" />          
                <CollectionView  ItemsSource="{Binding formViewerElements}" >              
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>                            
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{Binding color}">
                                <Label Text="{Binding text}" >
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
```

BindingContext in code behind:

```
          this.BindingContext = new FormViewerViewModell();
```

ViewModell:

```
 public class FormViewerViewModell : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public FormViewerViewModell()
    {  
     GenerateData
    }
    private FormChooseElement FormChooseElement;
    public FormChooseElement formChooseElement
    {
        get => FormChooseElement;
        set
        {
            FormChooseElement = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FormChooseElement));
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<FormViewerElement> formViewerElements
    {
        get => formChooseElement.formViewerElements;
        set
        {                formChooseElement.formViewerElements = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(formChooseElement.formViewerElements));

        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

FormChooseElement

```
    public class FormChooseElement
{
    public ...
    public ObservableCollection<FormViewerElement> formViewerElements { get; set; }
}
```

FormViewerElement

```
  public class FormViewerElement
{
    public ...
    public ObservableCollection<FormViewerElementAnsware> formViewerElementAnswares { get; set; }
}
```

FormViewerElementAnsware

```
public class FormViewerElementAnsware
{
    public ...
    public Color color { get; set; };
```

Comment: You should just be able to make `FormViewerElementAnsware` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and make `color` raise the event

Comment: Wow. I forgot this. Thank you! Its working :D

Comment: @gyb001, if this solved your problem, please post the answer and accept it so that it is clear to all that your problem is solved. Thanks